# SavGol Filter gives same length error on 3-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filtering

Hi, I'm trying to apply a [Sav-gol filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) to a 3D array of data that I have, (magnetic field data with xyz coordinates.) When I run my program, I Get the error: TypeError: expected x and y to have same length. My array is 460798 units long, with each unit being some list of coordinates [x y z]. I think it has to do something with the window size parameter. When I put it to three, it works fine, but my data points aren't smoothed. Higher than three, it does not work.
   I am trying to get the function to smooth the 3-D array.

```
mag = cdf['Mag'][start_ind:stop_ind) #mag is a 3-D array with coordinate element [x y z]
mag_smoothed = signal.savgol_filter(x=mag, window_length=5, polyorder=2)
print mag_smoothed[1]
```

I'm supposed to get a smoothed 3-D array back, I believe.

```
File "/Users/sosa/research/Python Files/MagnometerPlot.py", line 33, in plot
mag_smoothed = signal.savgol_filter(x=mag, window_length=7, polyorder=2,axis=1)
File "/Users/sosa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/_savitzky_golay.py", line 339, in savgol_filter
_fit_edges_polyfit(x, window_length, polyorder, deriv, delta, axis, y)
File "/Users/sosa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/_savitzky_golay.py", line 217, in _fit_edges_polyfit
polyorder, deriv, delta, y)
File "/Users/sosa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/signal/_savitzky_golay.py", line 187, in _fit_edge
xx_edge, polyorder)
File "/Users/sosa/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 559, in polyfit
raise TypeError("expected x and y to have same length")
TypeError: expected x and y to have same length
```

Comment: According to the docs, the scipy savitzky-golay filter is a 1D-filter. You could try specifying an axis (`axis=0/1/2`). But with this filter you'll only be able to filter the signal one axis at a time and you'll have to think about whether that's adequate for your purposes.

Comment: @ikom, do you think if I separate the x,y,z components of the mag list and apply the filter separately to each component, would the filter be replicated?

Answer (score 0):

> do you think if I separate the x,y,z components of the mag list and apply the filter separately to each component, would the filter be replicated?

I think it could be a reasonable approximation, but that's highly subjective and depends on what you're planning to do with your data. If you're trying to do precision measurements this might not be the best way to process your data. 
Since I'm not sure if you're working with volume data or surface data (with z being the magnitude at x, y). I'll use a 3D-surface as an example. (Let's say it's a 2D array of magnitudes, `arr1`)

What we want to do: Smooth the surface with SG.

What we can do with scipy's SG-Filter: Smooth a 1D line.

But a surface is just a set of lines side by side, so to work around it we might do the following:

1) Smooth every row in `arr1` (axis = 0). We put all the smoothed rows into a new array, `arr2`

2) Now we do the same with every *column* in `arr2` (axis=1) and generate `arr3`, which is, nominally, the "2D-smoothed" surface.

But it isn't, not quite. For a given data point, the 1D-filter calculates a new values by taking into acount the point itself and several adjacent values. But in a 2D-set, that data point has *more* adjacent values which the 1D-filter doesn't see, because those values are in the wrong row (or column). It would probably arrive at a different value if it could.

The easiest way to convince yourself that the step-wise smoothing isn't perfect is to do it twice, but the second time you reverse the order. First you work along columns, then rows. In a perfect world the final results should agree, whether you started with rows or columns. As it is you'll probably find they're slightly different.

If your data is quite uniform without many 'jagged' peaks or jumps (e.g. noise) you probably wouldn't have any problems. Otherwise you may see more significant differences between the two results.

A quick google search did show up various discussions about 2D-Savitzky-Golay filters, so investigating that might be worthwhile for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your data are organized in columns, you have to use

`mag_smoothed = signal.savgol_filter(x=mag, window_length=5, polyorder=2, axis=0)`